# Select rows from table 1 only if all corresponding rows have certain status in the join table

Tags: mysql, join

These are the tables

**Orders**

- id
- status

**Order_lines**

- id
- order_id

**Invoice_lines**

- id
- invoice_id
- order_line_id

**Invoices**

- id
- status

I would like to retrieve only orders whose invoices are in approved or closed status. If any invoices are in open status, that order should not be selected

I tried this

```
 SELECT o.id FROM orders o INNER JOIN order_lines ol ON ol.orders_id = o.id 
                     INNER JOIN invoice_lines il ON il.order_line_id = ol.id 
                     INNER JOIN invoices i ON i.id = il.invoice_id 
                     AND i.status IN ('approved', 'closed')
```

I keep getting orders which have invoices in open state. This is not the result I want. I want orders for whose invoices are only in approved and closed status

Comment: Not sure I understand your design. Why do invoice_lines contain an order_line_id? Is there not an order_id per invoice?

Comment: This is the current design and there is no order_id in the invoice.

Comment: One order has many "lines", correct?  Order_lines and invoices are in a many-to-many relationship?  Possibly an invoice spans multiple orders?  Something seems wrong.

Comment: What are all of the possible values for `invoices.status`?  you state "invoices are only in approved **and** closed status", which, to me, means you have at least 2 invoices records ... one with `status=approved` and one with `status=closed` ... correct? I recommend you take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then come back and update your question accordingly ... in this case the table DDL, some sample data, and the desired results would be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues I'll have to gloss over at this point due to lack of info:

- no DDL; no sample data; no list of valid `invoices.status` values
- "invoices are only in approved **and** closed status" implies an invoice needs at least 2 records ... one with `status='approved'` and one with `status='closed'`

Instead of trying to find all orders with invoices that are a) 'approved' **and** 'closed', or b) 'approved' **or** 'closed' ... just look for orders that have no invoices with a status other than 'approved' or 'closed':

```
select distinct
       o.id
from   orders o
where not exists(select 1
                 from   order_lines ol
                 join   invoice_lines il
                 on     il.order_line_id = ol.id

                 join   invoices i
                 on     i.id = il.invoice_id
                 and    ifnull(i.status,'UNDEFINED') not in ('approved','closed')

                 where  ol.order_id = o.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at this - the design of the system seems strange - why you have to go from `orders-> order_lines -> invoice_lines -> invoices` strikes me as strange.

You should have a correspondance between invoices and orders. An extra level of complexity could be added by deliveries - with many orders being fulfilled by many deliveries, partial-billing based on fulfillment and various other factors.

I created a few tables using PostgreSQL (don't have a running MySQL instance), the basic concepts should be readily transferrable between the two.

I then ran a query which runs fine - you have to make sure you use a `SELECT DISTINCT(...) FROM ...` because the joining tables between `orders` and `invoice` have more records than those tables - naturally enough, order_line and invoice_line will have at least 1 record (and likely more) per order and invoice.

This is my query (tables - DDL and DML at the end of the post).

```
SELECT DISTINCT (T.my_orders) 
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    o.orders_id AS my_orders, 
    o.orders_client, 
    p.product_name, 
    ol.order_line_id, 
    ol.order_line_product_id,
    il.invoice_line_order_line_id, 
    il.invoice_line_id, 
    il.invoice_line_invoice_id,
    inv.invoice_id, 
    inv.invoice_client, 
    inv.invoice_status, 
    s.status_name
  FROM orders o
  LEFT JOIN order_line ol ON ol.order_line_orders_id = o.orders_id
  LEFT JOIN product p     ON p.product_id = ol.order_line_product_id
  LEFT JOIN invoice_line il ON il.invoice_line_order_line_id = ol.order_line_id
  LEFT JOIN invoice inv ON inv.invoice_id = il.invoice_line_invoice_id
  LEFT JOIN status s    ON s.status_id = inv.invoice_status
  WHERE s.status_name IN ('Approved', 'Closed')
) AS T;
```

What I find helpful is to bring in (far) more fields than are needed in the first pass in order to clarify the relationships between the tables and also the cardinality of the result sets - **then** you pare it down to the minimum needed for your desired result - and if you run the SQL above on the tables below, you will find the `orders` whose status is as required. Try running the inner SQL statement on your the data and understand where the result is coming from...

I "translated" your query so it would work with my tables (the only time I use a plural table name is for `orders` - everything else is singular) and I use `table_name_id` as my `PRIMARY KEY`, not just `id` - better for debugging - you know where the problem has come from!

```
SELECT DISTINCT(o.orders_id) 
FROM orders o 
INNER JOIN order_line ol ON ol.order_line_orders_id = o.orders_id 
INNER JOIN invoice_line il ON il.invoice_line_order_line_id = ol.order_line_id 
INNER JOIN invoice i ON i.invoice_id = il.invoice_line_invoice_id 
AND i.invoice_status IN (1, 2)
```

Your SQL gives the same result as mine - so I'm just wondering if there are fields and/or other issues with the schema as described? I don't see how (with my schema), you could possibly get any orders with a status other than 1 or 2 - which correspond to 'Accepted' and 'Closed' in my schema.

## SQL STATEMENTS:

```
  -- /******************** STATUS ***************************/


DROP TABLE status CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE status
(
  status_id SERIAL, CONSTRAINT status_pk PRIMARY KEY (status_id),
  status_name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT status_name_uq UNIQUE (status_name)
);

ALTER SEQUENCE status_status_id_seq RENAME TO status_id_seq;

INSERT INTO status (status_name) VALUES ('Approved');
INSERT INTO status (status_name) VALUES ('Closed');
INSERT INTO status (status_name) VALUES ('Open');
INSERT INTO status (status_name) VALUES ('Cancelled');

DROP TABLE product CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE product
(
  product_id SERIAL, CONSTRAINT product_pk PRIMARY KEY (product_id),
  product_name VARCHAR(15), CONSTRAINT product_name_uq UNIQUE (product_name)
);

ALTER SEQUENCE product_product_id_seq RENAME TO product_id_seq;

INSERT INTO product (product_name) VALUES ('Product 1'), ('Product 2');


  -- /******************* CLIENT ******************************/

DROP TABLE client CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE client
(
  client_id SERIAL, CONSTRAINT client_pk PRIMARY KEY (client_id),
  client_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT client_name_uq UNIQUE (client_name)
);

ALTER SEQUENCE client_client_id_seq RENAME TO client_id_seq;

INSERT INTO client (client_name) VALUES ('Client 1');
INSERT INTO client (client_name) VALUES ('Client 2');
INSERT INTO client (client_name) VALUES ('Client 3');
INSERT INTO client (client_name) VALUES ('Client 4');


  -- /******************** ORDERS *****************************/

DROP TABLE ORDERS CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE orders
(
  orders_id SERIAL, CONSTRAINT order_pk PRIMARY KEY (orders_id),
  orders_client INTEGER, CONSTRAINT orders_client_fk FOREIGN KEY (orders_client) REFERENCES client (client_id)
  -- orders_status INTEGER, CONSTRAINT orders_order_status_fk FOREIGN KEY (orders_status) REFERENCES status (status_id)
);

ALTER SEQUENCE orders_orders_id_seq RENAME TO orders_id_seq;

INSERT INTO orders (orders_id, orders_client) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO orders (orders_id, orders_client) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO orders (orders_id, orders_client) VALUES (3, 2);
INSERT INTO orders (orders_id, orders_client) VALUES (4, 2);
INSERT INTO orders (orders_id, orders_client) VALUES (5, 3);
INSERT INTO orders (orders_id, orders_client) VALUES (6, 3);
INSERT INTO orders (orders_id, orders_client) VALUES (7, 4);
INSERT INTO orders (orders_id, orders_client) VALUES (8, 4);


-- /******************** INVOICE *******************/

DROP TABLE invoice CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE invoice
(
  invoice_id SERIAL, CONSTRAINT invoice_pk PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id),
  invoice_client INTEGER, CONSTRAINT invoice_client_fk FOREIGN KEY (invoice_client) REFERENCES client (client_id),
  invoice_status INTEGER, CONSTRAINT invoice_status_fk FOREIGN KEY (invoice_status) REFERENCES status (status_id)
);

ALTER SEQUENCE invoice_invoice_id_seq RENAME TO invoice_id_seq;

ALTER SEQUENCE invoice_id_seq RESTART WITH 31;

INSERT INTO invoice (invoice_client, invoice_status) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO invoice (invoice_client, invoice_status) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO invoice (invoice_client, invoice_status) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO invoice (invoice_client, invoice_status) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO invoice (invoice_client, invoice_status) VALUES (3, 3);
INSERT INTO invoice (invoice_client, invoice_status) VALUES (3, 3);
INSERT INTO invoice (invoice_client, invoice_status) VALUES (4, 4);
INSERT INTO invoice (invoice_client, invoice_status) VALUES (4, 4);

-- /********************* ORDER_LINE *************************/

DROP TABLE order_line CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE order_line
(
  order_line_id SERIAL,          CONSTRAINT order_line_pk PRIMARY KEY (order_line_id),
  order_line_orders_id  INTEGER, CONSTRAINT order_line_orders_fk FOREIGN KEY (order_line_orders_id) REFERENCES orders (orders_id),
  order_line_product_id INTEGER, CONSTRAINT order_line_product_fk FOREIGN KEY (order_line_product_id) REFERENCES product (product_id)
--   order_line_invoice_id INTEGER, CONSTRAINT order_line_invoice_fk FOREIGN KEY (order_line_invoice_id) REFERENCES invoice (invoice_id)
);

ALTER SEQUENCE order_line_order_line_id_seq RENAME TO order_line_id_seq;

ALTER SEQUENCE order_line_id_seq RESTART WITH 1001;

INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (3, 1);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (3, 2);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (4, 1);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (4, 2);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (5, 1);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (5, 2);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (6, 1);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (6, 2);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (7, 1);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (7, 2);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (8, 1);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (8, 2);


  -- /********************* INVOICE_LINE ****************************/

DROP TABLE invoice_line;
CREATE TABLE invoice_line 
(
  invoice_line_id SERIAL,     CONSTRAINT invoice_line_pk PRIMARY KEY (invoice_line_id),
  invoice_line_invoice_id INTEGER,    CONSTRAINT invoice_line_invoice_fk FOREIGN KEY (invoice_line_invoice_id) REFERENCES invoice (invoice_id),
  invoice_line_order_line_id INTEGER, CONSTRAINT invoice_line_order_line_fk FOREIGN KEY (invoice_line_order_line_id) REFERENCES order_line (order_line_id) 
);

ALTER SEQUENCE invoice_line_invoice_line_id_seq RENAME TO invoice_line_id_seq;
ALTER SEQUENCE invoice_line_id_seq RESTART WITH 5001;

INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (31, 1001);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (31, 1002);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (32, 1003);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (32, 1004);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (33, 1005);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (33, 1006);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (34, 1007);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (34, 1008);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (35, 1009);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (35, 1010);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (36, 1011);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (36, 1012);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (37, 1013);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (37, 1014);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (38, 1015);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (38, 1016);
```

## DATA DUMP:

You can just take the `INSERT` statements and `CREATE TABLE` statements out - the data is consistent! The `SERIAL` stuff won't work for MySQL obviously!

```
CREATE TABLE client (
    client_id integer NOT NULL,
    client_name character varying(25) NOT NULL
);


ALTER TABLE client OWNER TO pol;

--
-- Name: client_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

CREATE SEQUENCE client_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;


ALTER TABLE client_id_seq OWNER TO pol;

--
-- Name: client_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE OWNED BY; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

ALTER SEQUENCE client_id_seq OWNED BY client.client_id;


--
-- Name: invoice; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

CREATE TABLE invoice (
    invoice_id integer NOT NULL,
    invoice_client integer,
    invoice_status integer
);


ALTER TABLE invoice OWNER TO pol;

--
-- Name: invoice_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

CREATE SEQUENCE invoice_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;


ALTER TABLE invoice_id_seq OWNER TO pol;

--
-- Name: invoice_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE OWNED BY; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

ALTER SEQUENCE invoice_id_seq OWNED BY invoice.invoice_id;


--
-- Name: invoice_line; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

CREATE TABLE invoice_line (
    invoice_line_id integer NOT NULL,
    invoice_line_invoice_id integer,
    invoice_line_order_line_id integer
);


ALTER TABLE invoice_line OWNER TO pol;

--
-- Name: invoice_line_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

CREATE SEQUENCE invoice_line_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;


ALTER TABLE invoice_line_id_seq OWNER TO pol;

--
-- Name: invoice_line_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE OWNED BY; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

ALTER SEQUENCE invoice_line_id_seq OWNED BY invoice_line.invoice_line_id;


--
-- Name: order_line; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

CREATE TABLE order_line (
    order_line_id integer NOT NULL,
    order_line_orders_id integer,
    order_line_product_id integer
);


ALTER TABLE order_line OWNER TO pol;

--
-- Name: order_line_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

CREATE SEQUENCE order_line_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;


ALTER TABLE order_line_id_seq OWNER TO pol;

--
-- Name: order_line_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE OWNED BY; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

ALTER SEQUENCE order_line_id_seq OWNED BY order_line.order_line_id;


--
-- Name: orders; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

CREATE TABLE orders (
    orders_id integer NOT NULL,
    orders_client integer
);


ALTER TABLE orders OWNER TO pol;

--
-- Name: orders_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

CREATE SEQUENCE orders_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;


ALTER TABLE orders_id_seq OWNER TO pol;

--
-- Name: orders_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE OWNED BY; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

ALTER SEQUENCE orders_id_seq OWNED BY orders.orders_id;


--
-- Name: product; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

CREATE TABLE product (
    product_id integer NOT NULL,
    product_name character varying(15)
);


ALTER TABLE product OWNER TO pol;

--
-- Name: product_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

CREATE SEQUENCE product_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;


ALTER TABLE product_id_seq OWNER TO pol;

--
-- Name: product_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE OWNED BY; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

ALTER SEQUENCE product_id_seq OWNED BY product.product_id;


--
-- Name: status; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

CREATE TABLE status (
    status_id integer NOT NULL,
    status_name character varying(10) NOT NULL
);


ALTER TABLE status OWNER TO pol;

--
-- Name: status_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

CREATE SEQUENCE status_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;


ALTER TABLE status_id_seq OWNER TO pol;

--
-- Name: status_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE OWNED BY; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

ALTER SEQUENCE status_id_seq OWNED BY status.status_id;


--
-- Name: client client_id; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY client ALTER COLUMN client_id SET DEFAULT nextval('client_id_seq'::regclass);


--
-- Name: invoice invoice_id; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY invoice ALTER COLUMN invoice_id SET DEFAULT nextval('invoice_id_seq'::regclass);


--
-- Name: invoice_line invoice_line_id; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY invoice_line ALTER COLUMN invoice_line_id SET DEFAULT nextval('invoice_line_id_seq'::regclass);


--
-- Name: order_line order_line_id; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY order_line ALTER COLUMN order_line_id SET DEFAULT nextval('order_line_id_seq'::regclass);


--
-- Name: orders orders_id; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY orders ALTER COLUMN orders_id SET DEFAULT nextval('orders_id_seq'::regclass);


--
-- Name: product product_id; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY product ALTER COLUMN product_id SET DEFAULT nextval('product_id_seq'::regclass);


--
-- Name: status status_id; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY status ALTER COLUMN status_id SET DEFAULT nextval('status_id_seq'::regclass);


--
-- Data for Name: client; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

INSERT INTO client (client_id, client_name) VALUES (1, 'Client 1');
INSERT INTO client (client_id, client_name) VALUES (2, 'Client 2');
INSERT INTO client (client_id, client_name) VALUES (3, 'Client 3');
INSERT INTO client (client_id, client_name) VALUES (4, 'Client 4');


--
-- Data for Name: invoice; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

INSERT INTO invoice (invoice_id, invoice_client, invoice_status) VALUES (31, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO invoice (invoice_id, invoice_client, invoice_status) VALUES (32, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO invoice (invoice_id, invoice_client, invoice_status) VALUES (33, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO invoice (invoice_id, invoice_client, invoice_status) VALUES (34, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO invoice (invoice_id, invoice_client, invoice_status) VALUES (35, 3, 3);
INSERT INTO invoice (invoice_id, invoice_client, invoice_status) VALUES (36, 3, 3);
INSERT INTO invoice (invoice_id, invoice_client, invoice_status) VALUES (37, 4, 4);
INSERT INTO invoice (invoice_id, invoice_client, invoice_status) VALUES (38, 4, 4);


--
-- Data for Name: invoice_line; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_id, invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (5001, 31, 1001);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_id, invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (5002, 31, 1002);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_id, invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (5003, 32, 1003);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_id, invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (5004, 32, 1004);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_id, invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (5005, 33, 1005);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_id, invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (5006, 33, 1006);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_id, invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (5007, 34, 1007);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_id, invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (5008, 34, 1008);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_id, invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (5009, 35, 1009);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_id, invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (5010, 35, 1010);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_id, invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (5011, 36, 1011);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_id, invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (5012, 36, 1012);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_id, invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (5013, 37, 1013);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_id, invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (5014, 37, 1014);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_id, invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (5015, 38, 1015);
INSERT INTO invoice_line (invoice_line_id, invoice_line_invoice_id, invoice_line_order_line_id) VALUES (5016, 38, 1016);


--
-- Data for Name: order_line; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_id, order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (1001, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_id, order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (1002, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_id, order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (1003, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_id, order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (1004, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_id, order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (1005, 3, 1);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_id, order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (1006, 3, 2);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_id, order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (1007, 4, 1);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_id, order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (1008, 4, 2);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_id, order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (1009, 5, 1);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_id, order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (1010, 5, 2);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_id, order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (1011, 6, 1);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_id, order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (1012, 6, 2);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_id, order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (1013, 7, 1);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_id, order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (1014, 7, 2);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_id, order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (1015, 8, 1);
INSERT INTO order_line (order_line_id, order_line_orders_id, order_line_product_id) VALUES (1016, 8, 2);


--
-- Data for Name: orders; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

INSERT INTO orders (orders_id, orders_client) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO orders (orders_id, orders_client) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO orders (orders_id, orders_client) VALUES (3, 2);
INSERT INTO orders (orders_id, orders_client) VALUES (4, 2);
INSERT INTO orders (orders_id, orders_client) VALUES (5, 3);
INSERT INTO orders (orders_id, orders_client) VALUES (6, 3);
INSERT INTO orders (orders_id, orders_client) VALUES (7, 4);
INSERT INTO orders (orders_id, orders_client) VALUES (8, 4);


--
-- Data for Name: product; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

INSERT INTO product (product_id, product_name) VALUES (1, 'Product 1');
INSERT INTO product (product_id, product_name) VALUES (2, 'Product 2');


--
-- Data for Name: status; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: pol
--

INSERT INTO status (status_id, status_name) VALUES (1, 'Approved');
INSERT INTO status (status_id, status_name) VALUES (2, 'Closed');
INSERT INTO status (status_id, status_name) VALUES (3, 'Open');
INSERT INTO status (status_id, status_name) VALUES (4, 'Cancelled');
```

Comment: The extra level complexity is because the invoice can have invoice lines from order lines of different orders. So this complicates the issue.